# Maven Basic Question

Tags: java, maven

```
mvn -DgroupId=org.epseelon.samples -DartifactId=todolist archetype:create
```

Can anyone explain me the command here.

1. What is DgroupID?
2. What is org.epseelon.samples
3. What is DartifactID = todolist
4. What is archetype and create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokens in this command line are:

- mvn
- -D
- groupId
- =
- org.epseelon.samples
- -D
- artifactId
- =
- todolist
- archetype:create

And here is the explanation:

- The `-D` means *define a property of the given name*, which is very generic. Almost everything can be handled and configured by it.
- `groupId` is the *namespace* in which your projects live. You should choose your own internet domain for it, in reversed order. For example, I usually choose `de.roland_illig.*`, replacing the `*` with the actual project name. This will lead to (redundant) *complete artifact names* like `de.roland_illig.todolist:todolist` but is useful if I later decide to split the project into several small libraries.
- `artifactId` is the project name itself. When you build a `.jar` file, the resulting file will have this name.
- `archetype` is the name of a Maven plug-in.
- `create` is an action that is defined by that plug-in.

Comment: "The -D means define a property of the given name, which is very generic. Almost everything can be handled and configured by it." -> where is the documentation for that? Its really bothering me. I only found it in mvn help (-D), not for the goal's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Getting started manual](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

- archetype:create is to create a project
- -DgroupId defines the group usually the domain e.g. `org.eclipse.visualedit` as a group of artifacts, the it could have a model, a gui and some other modules packed
- -DartifactId defines the artifact (e.g. a jar file) e.g. visedit-gui-1.0.jar which is one the element of the group.

Comment: actually todolist is the project name but u say its a jar

Comment: @theband artifact is the what is build by maven, it is the name of the produced file (typically the jar) and an Id (or the name) which is unique within the group.

Answer (score 0):

In maven [link text](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html) you define dependency on other packages/libraries with 3 parameters: `groupId:artifactId:version`. For details see [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates). Packages are stored in [central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).

Maven is also known for [plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html). Witch `archetype:create` you call plugin `archetype` and it's action `create` ([documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)).

The command `mvn ...` creates a new project based on specified jar `org.epseelon.samples:todolist`.